# Using PrincipalSearcher to find users matching pattern

Tags: c#, active-directory, userprincipal, principalsearcher

I have a somewhat particular situation I couldn't find answers to through google.

I need to query my active directory for users whose SAMAccountName fits a particular pattern (3 letters followed by 4 digits).

Currently I pull the entire list of users and filter it with regex client-side.

Can this somehow be done directly in the query so that only users with that matching field are returned from the server in the first place?

Comment: Any three letters followed by any four digits? Or are the letters always the same? Maybe can you give us the regex you use?

Comment: @GabrielLuci Any three letters followed by any four digits, yes. Both the letters and digits are randomly generated for each user.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the best you can do is limit it to accounts where the first character is a letter.

The only operators that could help are `>=` and `<=`. For example, you can have a filter like this:

```
(&(sAMAccountName>=A*)(sAMAccountName<=Z*))
```

That will exclude accounts that start with anything other than a letter. But there is no way to extend that to any more than just the first character.

I'm guessing that probably isn't going to help.

More reading: [Active Directory: LDAP Syntax Filters](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx)